# Checking if given coordinate (lat,long) is in raster image file (TIFF file) and how to extract it with NXN window

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, rasterio

I am researching to complete a project.

The aim is by given a coordinate I can extract the image among the raster files.

How do I check if the coordinate that I have for example (51.3334198, 3.2973934) is in a raster image file - k_01.tif?

If this coordinate is indeed in k_01.tif, how do I extract a small part of if i.e MxN window?

My code:

```py
import rasterio      
src = rasterio.open('k_01.tif')
src.bound

>BoundingBox(left=145000.0, bottom=238000.0, right=162000.0, top=247000.0)

src.crs

>CRS.from_epsg(31370)
```

@snowman2 gave the link [Extracting data from a raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358036/extracting-data-from-a-raster/358058#358058).

I followed the advice and my code as follow:

I used another .tif and another longitude and latitude.

```py
import rasterio
from pyproj import Transformer

lon = 4.2811439
lat = 51.2010511

path = './k15.tif'

with rasterio.open(path) as rds:
    # convert coordinate to raster projection
    transformer = Transformer.from_crs("EPSG:4326", rds.crs, always_xy=True)
    xx, yy = transformer.transform(lon, lat)

    # get value from grid
    value = list(rds.sample([(xx, yy)]))[0]

value 
> array([11.61], dtype=float32)

xx , yy

>(143876.25575738482, 210123.58613220416)


src.bounds

> BoundingBox(left=130000.0, bottom=198000.0, right=162000.0, top=218000.0)
```

[image]

From the result above I understand that xx,yy  is the conversion of the latitude and longitude and it is indeed in the boundary of the tif.

What is the value 11.6 for?

My second part of the question is how to extract the latitude and longitude with MxN window ?

As shown as picture below.

[image]

And crop it to just as follow?

[image]

Comment: Does this help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/358058/144357 ?

Comment: Thanks @snowman2 . I have followed your link and updated my questions as above.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are missing for is a combination of:

1. [index](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.io.html?highlight=xy#rasterio.io.DatasetReader.index)
2. [Window.from_slices](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.windows.html#rasterio.windows.Window.from_slices). Also see [windowed rw docs](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windowed-rw.html).

This should do it:

```py
import rasterio
from rasterio.windows import Window
from pyproj import Transformer

lon = 4.2811439
lat = 51.2010511

path = './k15.tif'

with rasterio.open(path) as rds:
    # convert coordinate to raster projection
    transformer = Transformer.from_crs("EPSG:4326", rds.crs, always_xy=True)
    xx, yy = transformer.transform(lon, lat)
    row, col = rds.index(xx, yy)
    window = Window.from_slices(rows=(row-2, row+2), cols=(col-2, col+2))
    data = rds.read(window=window)
```