# How to extract the elevation from GeoTIFF at an arbitrary point in latitude/longitude?

Tags: raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, rasterio

I want to extract the elevation at any point in longitude/latitude from GeoTIFF, similar to Global Mapper. Using GDAL and rasterio, I get an image with a size of (6000, 6000) points. And the distance between each point, when translated into meters, is 90 meters, and I need a step between the points of 10 meters. Is it possible using raster libraries to get a result where the elevation is calculated based on the gradient of the raster, as Global Mapper does?

I use simple code:

```py
from osgeo import gdal
import os
import geopy.distance

gdal_data = gdal.Open("./n50e045_dem.tif", gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
raster_band = gdal_data.GetRasterBand(1)
raster = raster_band.ReadAsArray()
print(raster.size, raster.shape)  
>>> 36000000 (6000, 6000)


width = gdal_data.RasterXSize
height = gdal_data.RasterYSize
i_x = 4315
i_y = 861
X = gt[0] + i_x*gt[1] + i_y*gt[2]
Y = gt[3] + i_x*gt[4] + i_y*gt[5]
Z = raster[i_y, i_x] # in array elevations
coords_1 = (54.282916666666665, 48.595416666666665)
coords_2 = (Y, X)
print (geopy.distance.geodesic(coords_1, coords_2).m)  
>>> 92.75854901199543
```

I need 10 meters instead of 90.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. It is not possible to express a uniform conversion of degrees to meters, because all the meridians converge at the poles and even latitudes are not uniform due to oblateness. You can interpolate across three arc-second pixels, but the results are far from perfect. "Is it possible?" questions ask the wrong question -- what you really want is "How is it possible to..." We expect that your Question will include what you've tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting data from a raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358036/extracting-data-from-a-raster)

Comment: I don't *think* this is a duplicate. The desired result seems to be an interpolation of Z values between cell centroids (e.g. [1](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/issues/382), [2](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend first resampling the raster to 10 meters, then extract the points.

Step 1: Resample raster to 10 meters

- https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/reproject.html
- https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reproject.html
- https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resampling.html

Step 2: Extract data
[Extracting data from a raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358036/extracting-data-from-a-raster)